# I need an Access database that will be used by about 6-10 people, but not on a share drive

Tags: database, ms-access

I work on a project that has very well defined lines of responsibility. There are about six to ten of us and we currently do all of our work in Excel, building a single spreadsheet with maintenance requirements for ships. A couple of times during the project process we stop all work and compile all of the individual spreadsheets into one spreadsheet. Since each person had a well defined area, we don't have to worry about one person overwriting another person's work. It only takes an hour, so it isn't that huge of a deal. Less than optimal, sure, but it gets the job done.

But each person fills out their data differently. I think moving to a database would serve us well by making the data more regimented with validation rules. But the problem is, we do not have any type of share drive or database server where we can host the database, and that won't change. I was wondering if there was a simple solution similar to the way we were handling the Excel spreadsheet. I envisioned a process where I would wipe the old data and then import the new data. But I suspect that will bring up other problems.

I am pretty comfortable building small databases and using VBA and whatnot. This project would probably have about six tables, and probably three that would have the majority of the data for any given project (the others would be reference tables and slow-to-change data). Bottom line is, I am wondering if it is worth it, or should I stick with Excel?

Comment: How do you envisage merging the data, do you want to merge all copies of the DB into one?

Comment: If you don't have a shared server of your own, what about a cloud server? For example, you can get a small SQL database on Azure for about $5/month. I don't know where you can get an Access database, but I'm sure there are hosting companies out there which offer that - maybe look into web hosting companies, and you may find a cheap one that offers Access - then just use it for the database.

Comment: Right now we do all of the merging by email. Each person sends their particular data via email and it is all assembled and the redistributed. Using a cloud server sounds great, but this is for a government office that is compiling business sensitive data, so nothing like this could be outsourced. Sadly, it will need to be pure desktop. @bendataclear, as for how I would merge the data, I think that is the crux of the problem. I was hoping someone would chime in and say "I solved a similar problem by doing XXX".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Access 2007 onwards has an option for "Collecting email replies" which can organise flat data, but it can only be a single query that's populated so might be a bit limiting.

The only solution I can think of that's easier than you currently use is to create the DB with some VBA modules that export all new/updated data to an XML/csv file and attached this to an email. You'd then have to create a VBA module that would import the data from these files into the current table.

It's a fair amount of work to get set up but once working might be fairly quick and robust.

**Edit**, just to add, I have solved a similar problem but I solved it with VB.net and XML files rather than Access.

Answer (score 0):

You can link Access databases to other databases (or import from them). So you can distribute a template database for users to add records to and then email back. When receiving back, you would either import or link them to a master database and do whatever you needed to do with the combined data.